# CORS Configuration in AWS console not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I have some JavaScript trying to make an ajax request to an RSS feed on a server that is hosted on AWS, I am getting the following error message when making the request:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.domain.com/feed. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://xxx.compute.amazonaws.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

I checked the request headers and the `Origin` header is there.

I then updated the CORS configuration on the server for the AWS bucket the ajax request is being sent to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://xxx.compute.amazonaws.com</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I also tried a few other different variations for the above, but none of them seemed to make a difference, my browser still gives the same CORS error message. When I installed a Chrome extension to disable CORS protection, the code worked perfectly, so it seems like it's only the CORS issue that's stopping it from working.

Does anyone know why the CORS configuration for the bucket in AWS isn't working, or why the configuration might be wrong?

I've been trying for a few days now but all the answers I find are people not realising you need to allow cross-origin sharing for external domains, or basic tutorials for how to configure CORS on AWS but I'm following those exactly and it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Could it be that the browser has cached the object from before you configured CORS, so isn't actually trying to load it again?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I've tried it in different browsers and cleared the cache, the browser doesn't seem to be the problem, I suspect it's on the AWS/server side.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was going on here? I seem to be having the same issue. I have two buckets, for two apps, each with the exact same CORS configuration (with the exception of the domain name in the Origin), and yet one of the apps is able to make requests successfully while the other is denied. Strangely, the configuration I was attempting to replace was `<AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>`. After unsuccessfully changing it to the actual origin, I can't even get it working again after changing it back to the wildcard. It's almost as if AWS isn't recognizing the latest file.

Comment: @jprince I've updated the post with the answer to my problem, I hope it helps you with yours.

Comment: @chris thank you for the update. I don't really like the idea of allowing any origin to post to my bucket, so I'll probably reach out to Amazon regarding this. I'll report back if anything comes of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to resolve this error by adding the following to my bucket's CORS configuration:

```
<AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
```

Full config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://my-subdomain.my-domain.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get it to work for a specific origin, and is something I still need to look at, but the following configuration worked for what I needed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```